# Trebuchet search application by name

Tags: applications, cyanogenmod, launcher, search, trebuchet

I use CyanogenMod 12.1 (Android 5.1.1) with the Trebuchet launcher.

How can I search for an app by its name, if I don't want to have the Google search installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, it is not possible. So I need to use en external app for this. I found [KISS launcher](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=fr.neamar.kiss) and [Hayai Launcher](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.hayaisoftware.launcher) which both do a great job.